# Problema com título e botão estáticos

Tags: html5, css3

Estou tendo problema com um H1 e um link com classe dentro de uma div, que não sobem ou descem do jeito que quero. Já tentei resolver isso usando `margin-top` e `margin-bottom`, mas não obtive o efeito que almejo. Quando uso essas propriedades, acontece colapso. Eles ficam *dentro* de uma imagem, inserida via **CSS** Segue código:

```css
.container {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.hero-image {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/uCRNEAF.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 1.2em;
}

.hero-image h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

/* Button */
.botao {
   font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
   color: #ffffff;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 5px 10px;
   background-color: #1989ca;
   font-size: 0.9em;
   border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hero-image">
  <h1>ESTE É MEU TÍTULO!</h1>
<a href="#botao" class="botao" title="Botão">HISTÓRIA</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Qual o comportamento que você está procurando?

Comment: Opa Thiago. É o alinhamento central desse título da tag H1 e o botão logo abaixo, porém com um espaçamento entre eles. O que estou tentando fazer é colocá-los ambos mais para cima.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu alterei um pouco os teus estilos para que ficasse mais fácil editar, eu apliquei um `padding: 250px;` na classe `.hero-image` e manipulei a `margin-top` e `margin-bottom` do H1 livremente:

```css
.container {
    width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.hero-image {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/uCRNEAF.jpg');
    padding: 250px;
    text-align: center;
}

.hero-image h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

/* Button */
.botao {
   font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
   color: #ffffff;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 5px 10px;
   background-color: #1989ca;
   font-size: 0.9em;
   border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hero-image">
  <h1>ESTE É MEU TÍTULO!</h1>
<a href="#botao" class="botao" title="Botão">HISTÓRIA</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, **Thiago**! Grande abraço.